# How do I transpose a view's frame to it's superview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Not even sure how to ask this.  Transpose local coordinates to global?

Comment: This operation is generally known as transforming, rather than transposing. I was searching for just this answer, but as "transform subview coordinates to superview coordinates". Thanks, @progrmr .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UIView class has a handful of methods for converting coordinates of CGPoints or CGRects from one view to another.  Take a look at [convertPoint:toView:, convertPoint:fromView:, etc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW52) in the UIView class reference.

You can convert coordinates from one view to another or from any view to the window or vice versa.